# como trabalhar com gênero e espécie de varias tabelas unificando elas para gráficos

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou a 3 semanas estudando java, possuo uma planilha e nela costa. Gênero e dentro dele a espécie isso na coluna 1 do Excel.
Na coluna 2 possui a quantidade de indivíduos dessa espécie em um determinado volume.
Na coluna 3 a quantidade de células da espécie por determinado volume.
 tabela no link

essa planilha (sendo arquivos em que cada arquivo é um ponto ou no mesmo arquivo, com varias tabelas, sendo cada tabela um ponto) representa uma localidade (ponto1 ou Ponto2....).
se eu possuir 2 pontos e sei que nesses pontos pode ter espécies diferente e iguais, como eu consigo juntar isso e fazer um gráfico para compara os pontos. estou tentando automatizar essa rotina pois eu perco muito tempo fazendo manualmente. procurei na internet e não achei nada nesse sentido.
Gostaria de saber qual biblioteca caso tenha para fazer ou se eu devo fazer em banco de dados e depois puxar... Obrigado.

[image: Fiz em html para demonstrar]
 cada ponto representa um arquivo/tabela no Excel pois possuo as duas opções

Comment: Olá, meio complexo isso mas não impossível, posso dar uma ideia apenas com a parte para unir elas. Eu utilizaria as lib do "Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents", com ela vai conseguir ler, criar e alterar um arquivo XLSX. A Lib é bem completa, vai conseguir pegar dados de uma linha ou coluna específica, eu tentaria criar um código para ler os dois arquivos, pegar os dados que deseja dos dois (Ind/L e Cel/L) e ai criar um novo arquivo com desses dados.

Comment: Obrigado pelo norte!!!

Comment: Para te ajudar na parte dos gráficos e ajudar possíveis pessoas que venham a ter essa dúvida no futuro, irei formular uma resposta, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou sim. Eu vou estudar e se eu conseguir resolver eu posto a solução. Acho que ate semana que vem eu consigo  ou não kkkk

Answer (score 1):

O código em si é meio difícil de te responder, mas existem bibliotecas que irão te ajudar a unificar essas tabelas e a gerar gráficos depois.

- *Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents*: Com esse pacote de libs você consiguirá ler, criar e alterar um arquivo XLSX. A biblioteca é extremamente completa, te permitirá a manipular os dados da forma que precisa.
- *JFreeChart*: Possibilitar a geração de relatórios na forma de gráficos, uma dica é utilizar o Apache POI em conjunto com ele, assim poderá ler um determinado arquivo e assim gerar o gráfico com o JFreeChart.

Links que ajudarão:

- [Apache POI: Manipulando Documentos em Java](https://www.devmedia.com.br/apache-poi-manipulando-documentos-em-java/31778)
- [Gráficos com JFreeChart](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/graficos-com-jfreechart/)
- [Tutorial de como ler um arquivo XLSX com Apache POI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH5Yu34Unvg)
- [Repositório Maven do JFreeChart](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart)
- [Tutorial utilizando JFreeChart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-oErHhT1Hw)

Comment: Opa. Obrigado pela dica do JFreeChart. Agora é por a mão na massa e resolvendo eu posto aqui.